# Devise after_sign_up_for path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I read all the thread on this, but I still can't figure out what is wrong. I have gone through all the devise implementation guides and followed them but after a new user registration, the redirect goes to the users controller, specifically users#show.

The initial call to a new registration is going through my registrations controller. That has been verified. But after the registration it doesn't pass through the registrations controller again. It goes through the users controller. I put a break in the two overriding methods in the new registrations controller and they never hit.

/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'app#index'

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

  resources :users do
    member do
      put 'follow', to: 'users#follow'
      put 'unfollow', to: 'users#unfollow'
    end
  end

end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
protected
  #call for new registration does pass through here
  #after new registration does not pass through here


  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    #never gets here after new registration
    other_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    #never gets here after new registration
    other_path(resource)
  end

end
```

new registration form:

```
  <form action="index.html">

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border" %>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Confirm Password", class: "form-control rounded input-lg text-center no-border"  %>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox i-checks m-b">
      <label class="m-l">
        <input type="checkbox" checked=""><i></i> Agree the <a href="#">terms and policy</a>
      </label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning lt b-white b-2x btn-block btn-rounded"><i class="icon-arrow-right pull-right"></i><span class="m-r-n-lg">Sign up</span></button>
    <% end %>

    <div class="text-center m-t m-b"><small><%= link_to "Already have an account?", new_session_path(resource_name) %></small></div>
```

console:

```
Started GET "/users/index.html?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=KlAk4ctYpw%2F2eHGqZ0OsAymf5BxUPxeBiFzeOatn2JDUQJdPk8fGoB%2BmuN4oeN3KviQdVwN%2FxMfnjH4zIVooOg%3D%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=asdf%40asdf.com&user
%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=[FILTERED]" for ::1 at 2016-10-25 22:10:37 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KlAk4ctYpw/2eHGqZ0OsAymf5BxUPxeBiFzeOatn2JDUQJdPk8fGoB+muN4oeN3KviQdVwN/xMfnjH4zIVooOg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"asdf@asdf.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]
", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "id"=>"index"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=index):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:6:in `show'
  Rendering /Users/Joe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/Joe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Joe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.7ms)
  Rendering /Users/Joe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Joe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendering /Users/Joe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Joe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/Joe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (69.3ms)
```

request params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"KlAk4ctYpw/2eHGqZ0OsAymf5BxUPxeBiFzeOatn2JDUQJdPk8fGoB+muN4oeN3KviQdVwN/xMfnjH4zIVooOg==",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"asdf@asdf.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "id"=>"index",
 "format"=>"html"}
```

Comment: paste your complete registration controller. your registration method create is wrong, the form should redirect to `registrations create`, but it is going to users show, your form has wrong url. pls paste the form

Comment: @Sravan That was it!! There was an extra leading form tag going to index.html. Updated code above for display. The extra form tag was leftover from a previous bit of code.

Comment: is it done now? if not, what  is your path for registrations controller

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to `users#show`, the correct path helper should be `user_path(resource)`, is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is two-fold. The registrations controller is looking for the incorrect path but it also needs a proper id. I think the solution here is to pass it `user_path(@user.id)` instead of having resource as an argument where you have it in `new_user_path(resource)`.

It's attempting to query for a User that has an ID of "Index" which doesn't exist and therefore it's throwing an error. You'll want to find the `id` of your new user and insert that to the route so that it finds that specific User profile. I used @user as an example. You can define that variable in the code or work with whatever variable you wish. I hope that helps!